# How to remove call stack on failed Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

When one of my Gulp task fails it prints out the error to console like this.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 12 (1 FAILED) (0.355 secs / 0.43 secs)
[20:18:42] 'client-test' errored after 15 s
[20:18:42] Error: Karma exited with status code 1
    at /home/blacksonic/workspace/angular2-webpack-es6-starter/tasks/client_test.js:15:21
    at removeAllListeners (/home/blacksonic/workspace/angular2-webpack-es6-starter/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:336:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/blacksonic/workspace/angular2-webpack-es6-starter/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:347:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1519:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```

Is there a way to remove this long call stack and just display the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Use Gulp's built-in on error event in your pipe like so;

```
gulp.src(file.path)
      .pipe('-- Your script --')
        .on('error', function(){ 
              // Log a smaller version of the error
              // or do nothing. Whatever you want
            })
      .pipe('-- Your other script --')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('-- You know the drill --'))
```

You should equip yourself with a nice logger such as the logger from [gulp-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util)

That would turn the code above into:

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins');

gulp.src(file.path)
          .pipe('-- Your script --')
            .on('error', function(){ 
                   $.util.log('Hey! something broke');
                })
          .pipe('-- Your other script --')
          .pipe(gulp.dest('-- You know the drill --'))
```